# Remove Exchange 2010 from a server where Active Directory does not exist anymore

Tags: exchange-2010, uninstall

Someone did a dcpromo and removed Active Directory on a box that's running Exchange 2010 *before* removing Exchange (why it was also a DC, I have no idea).

My only goal is to salvage the OS install; the server is now a "loaner" Windows Workgroup server (2008 R2 Standard) and has some other apps on it I'd rather not have to reinstall.

I've tried disabling all the Exchange services, but the uninstaller still complains about not finding the DC.  I suppose I could just leave the services disabled, but I'd rather cleanly remove Exchange if possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you re-promote it to try to remove Exchange when it's a DC again?

Comment: No sure if any of the AD objects that Exchange requires will be there in a new AD domain/forest.

Comment: Ahh, it was the only DC - gotcha.  Yeah, that won't work.

Comment: Have you adjusted the DNS config on the server to point to some other internal DNS?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you don't want to salvage anything Exchange related on the box.  If so, why not forcibly remove the services using **sc delete**, remove any orphaned keys under **HKLM\System\CurrentContolSet\Services**, then blow away the **HKLM\Software\Exchange** and **HKLM\Software\Exchange Server** keys.  Finally, delete the binaries from the disk.

Normally, the biggest concern about buggered up MSEXCH installs is tidying up AD, but it looks like this isn't an issue...

Comment: Perfect.  Let me give that a shot on Monday.